# How do I investigate why windowserver goes high cpu on mac?

Tags: macos

I am running 10.13.6 (17G65), sometimes playing several youtube videos simultaneously won't cause any problem, sometimes playing only single one youtube video causes windowserver, chrome and chrome(GPU) going high CPU usage.

How do I investigate the cause?

[image]

Comment: Similar question>>>>>https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153397/windowserver-high-cpu-on-yosemite

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Moab Mac computers are on topic here. The question belongs here just as much as anywhere else. https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've narrowed it down to Chrome, but it seems to be particularly bad when I have my 2017 MBP connected to two external monitors. I just switch to Safari when I am connected. Super annoying, but I don't want to investigate the time to figure out a proper solution.